# Program asks for 2 doubles even when no exception thrown

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class xArrays {
    public static double total;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       double[] marks = new double[5];
       for (int i =0;i<5;i++){
           System.out.printf("Enter your marks for course %d : ",(i+1));
          try { input.nextDouble();}
           catch ( InputMismatchException e ){
               System.out.println("this doesn't work");
               input.next();
               continue;}
           marks[i] = input.nextDouble();

           total += marks[i];




       }
```

I would like it to ask for marks 1 and then move onto marks 2 but what it does is ask for mark 1, I input marks 1 and then have to input another number for it move on.

Comment: How is the [c++] tag relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the input you read with `input.nextDouble()` to anything. And prefer `marks.length` to hardcoding the number five. You wanted something like,

```
double[] marks = new double[5];
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Enter your marks for course %d : ", (i + 1));
    try {
        marks[i] = input.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.printf("%s is not a double.%n", input.nextLine());
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    total += marks[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `input.nextDouble()` twice. Move the assignment directly into the try-catch block and remove the second `input.nextDouble()`. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   System.out.printf("Enter your marks for course %d : ", (i + 1));
   try { 
      marks[i] = input.nextDouble();
   } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("this doesn't work");
      input.next();
      continue;
   }
   total += marks[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are using `input.nextDouble()` twice. In the `try`, use something like `value = input.nextDouble()`, and then after the `catch`, `marks[i] = value`